# How to add string on AxisX in winforms c# charts?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have chart where Y is float and X is string. I'm adding values by timer

```
string st = dt.ToString("MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
int ix1 = 0;  
        
if (i % 2 != 0) 
    ix1 = s.Points.AddXY(st, 100.5f);           
else 
    ix1 = s.Points.AddXY(st, 50.5f);
i++;
```

but in the end i get only

[image]

Why X is 0? XValueType is also string on form.

Answer (score 1):

`St` is a string, hence the overload will be:
 `public int AddXY (object xValue, params object[] yValue);`. 
Because its a string, I guess that string that passed as an object is interpreted to 0

`st` **must be a DateTime**

From [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection.addxy?view=netframework-4.8):

> In order for DateTime formatting to have an effect, a value must be a
> DateTime object.

Comment: This is correct. When added as strings the x-values are lost and only show in the labels. Adding code to set the xvaluetype to datetime and the format will make it a +1..